# Possible to determine who on the Internet is resetting (RST) my TCP connection?

Tags: tls, tcp, dpi

I am investigating censorship in India, and know with a high degree of confidence that it is being blocked based on the SNI extension in the TLS ClientHello.

[image: tcpdump from Wireshark]

I am in control of both the Client (in India) and the Server (in Germany). I suspect someone in India is looking at the SNI to block websites (as opposed to the DNS lookup, or the certificate in the ServerHello in TLSv1.2).

I decided to confirm this by doing the following - make a TLS connection WITH the SNI set to a blocked website (pornhub as an example) to **my own server**.

This is what I observed on the client (in India):

1. (TCP Success)
2. Send ClientHello with SNI = `pornhub.com`
3. Receive TCP RST (apparently) from the Server (suspected MiTM)
4. Subsequently receive some "legit" responses from REAL server - e.g. ServerHello (*AFTER* the initial TCP RST)
5. Client thinks TCP conn. is already reset, so it responds with RST

This is what I observed on the server (in Germany)

1. (TCP Success)
2. Receive ClientHello with SNI = `pornhub.com`
3. Send the `ServerHello` (note: The cert is for a different domain, since I guess in nginx if the SNI doesn't match it just sends default cert).
4. Receive TCP RST from the Client

```
+-----------------+                   +------------------------+               +-------------------+
|                 |                   |                        |               |                   |
|  Client         |                   |     INTERNET           |               |    Server         |
|  (India)        |                   |     (Global)           |               |    (Germany)      |
|                 |                   |                        |               |                   |
| 10.0.0.92       |                   |                        |               |95.217.167.10      |
+-------+---------+                   +-----------+------------+               +---------+---------+
        |                                         |                                      |
        |      TLS Client Hello (SNI=pornhub)     |   TLS Client Hello (SNI=pornhub)     |
        +---------------------------------------> | -----------------------------------> |
        |                                         |                                      |
        |        TCP RESET (from 95.217.167.10)   |                                      |
        | <---------------------------------------+                                      |
        |          where does this come from?     |                                      |
        |                                         |                                      |
        |                                         |                                      |
        |                                         |                                      |
        |           TLS Server Hello              |           TLS Server Hello           |
        |  <--------------------------------------+ <------------------------------------+
        |                                         |                                      |
        |                                         |                                      |
        |               TCP RESET                 |              TCP RESET               |
        | --------------------------------------> +----------------------------------->  |
        |                                         |                                      |
```

Since I am in control of the Server, I know that it did not actually send the initial TCP RST to the Client. Is there a way to determine *who* in the middle is sending the TCP RST?

As a sanity check, I also tried using the SNI of an "ok" domain - google.com. That works just fine:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 95.217.167.10:443 -servername google.com
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mijia.mywaifu.best
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Jul 22 13:03:02 2023 GMT
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mijia.mywaifu.best
notAfter=Jul 22 13:03:02 2023 GMT
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = mijia.mywaifu.best (Default cert on remote server)
```

and in the blocked case:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 95.217.167.10:443 -servername pornhub.com
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104     /* Connection reset by peer */
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 313 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I wanted to question my hosting provider, but I was wondering if I could first determine where the TCP RST is originating. I am 99% sure it is by the hosting provider, but theoretically they could say "it just originated from the internet and we only forwarded it to you". Though in a Great Firewall like scenario, it could actually originate from beyond the hosting provider.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272026/tcp-server-sends-rst-ack-immediately-after-receiving-syn-from-client and https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/why-do-i-see-a-rst-ack-packet-instead-of-a-rst-packet

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a security question but a basic networking question. The links above suggest that a firewall along the way blocked the connection. Perhaps your ISP. Nothing is "spoofed". Try `traceroute` to figure out how far the packets travel.

Comment: Running tcpdump on the server (which is mine as well) , I can see that it wasn't from the server. Regardless, I understand its not appropriate for this stackexchange. I'll try ServerFault. Thanks for the response

Comment: wait, what? I think you are getting your terms confused. Or you are not providing all the info. What do you control? What is the networking set up? You control both the client and server? And you are adding "pornhub.com" to the SNI even though the domain name and hostname don't match it? If so, that's a massive detail you omitted and affects your investigation. And this isn't on-topic at ServerFault.

Comment: @poiasd: It might be possible to set your own TTL on the connection to find out how far away from you the RST gets generated. I.e start with a larger TTL then decrease until you no longer get a RST - then you have how many hops from you the RST generating system is.

Comment: The TTL on the RST might also give a clue, e.g. if you get 60, it probably started as 63 and then went 3 hops to get to you, or 64 and then went 4 hops, or 252 probably started as 255, etc. (Just a clue, not an exact answer)

Comment: I am voting to reopen this because investigating an MITM in your network connection is "network security" according to the help center.

Comment: And finally, have you tried any other domain? You jump right over the fact that your server sends a certificate for a domain that is not for the domain in the SNI. Have you considered that this would have an effect? And, have you tried any other domain? Something that wouldn't be "censored"? Your experiment is skewed to try to confirm something "bad" but your approach and your data are not consistent with ruling out anything benign and mundane, "When you see hoofprints, think 'horses' not 'centaurs'" Confirm that something normal isn't happening.

Comment: One more thing: what's in the first RST ACK from the server? Since the server's response is the core thing you are asking about, why are you showing us the packet from the client?

Comment: This all seems like an improperly formed experiment and not a security issue. So, I'm not going to re-open this until you can show that there is some sort of security issue.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified I am running tcpdump on the server to see the packets it's sending out, which I've tried to show in the ASCII diagram. 

I've updated it to include an "OK" case (with SNI=google, same server IP). Initially I only wanted to understand _how_ to detect the source of the reset, so skimmed over other details. But I understand if that does not fall under a "security issue".

Comment: Ok, that last test is very useful and tells us a lot. Can you also include a screenshot from wireshark about the RST/ACK from the server? My original comment about `traceroute` is echoed by Steffan's comment about crafting a TTL. That's how you will find the approximate place the block is happening (it should at least narrow down if it is close to the client or the server).

Comment: In the end, this is looking like a networking engineering question and not a security question. But it ***is*** a fascinating puzzle. I've put the matter up for discussion here: https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/is-this-a-security-question-or-a-networking-question

Comment: Thanks. Let me attach more screenshots and the pcap as well. Cheers.

Comment: You would need to tcpdump on your modem i think and decrypt ssl. Or use something like openwrt where you duplicate the Wan port and capture the traffic. Or use fiddler and check what http does when you go to a blocked site